# KSQL connection error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, ksqldb

I am running Kafka and KSQL through Docker and whenever I am attempting to create a table using [KSQL Python](https://github.com/bryanyang0528/ksql-python), I get the following connection error alongside another error exception.

```sh
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

raise KSQLError(content.get("message"), content.get("error_code"), content.get("stackTrace"))
ksql.errors.KSQLError: ('Failed to prepare statement: Invalid config variable(s) in the WITH clause: KEY', 40001, None)
```

Here's the relevant Python code that I am running:

```py
from ksql import KSQLAPI

client = KSQLAPI('http://localhost:8088')

client.create_table(
        table_name='foobar',
        columns_type=['impedanceid varchar', 'impedance bytes'],
        topic='sse',
        value_format='JSON',
        key='impedanceid'
    )
print(client.ksql('show tables'))
```

However, when I only run `print(client.ksql('show tables'))`, I don't get any error but get the KSQL object as expected:

```sh
[{'@type': 'tables', 'statementText': 'show tables;', 'tables': [], 'warnings': []}]
```

I am confused at this moment why the connection error occurs when attempting to create a table but doesn't occur when showing all the tables. Any clue?

By the way, here's the relevant `docker-compose.yml` file if that's needed to build up the whole setup quickly.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 29093:29093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://192.168.178.218:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:latest
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:latest
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true
networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: kafka_docker_sse
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not a connection problem. It's a request error. `Invalid config variable(s) in the WITH clause: KEY`... Seems to say `key='impedanceid'` is the issue

Comment: That's odd. What could be wrong with the `key='impedanceid'`? Any clue on what would be the way to correctly set the `key`?